# Is it possible for a node to host multiple cluster in relation to Always On AG

Tags: sql-server-2014, availability-groups

[image]

In my example, I have 3 database servers with their own DR servers, own availability group, own clusters.  Is it possible to setup another server which can be part of the 3 clusters and be a secondary replica on each of them?

Comment: The cluster1,2,3 are SQL Server FCI ?

Comment: uh no. just Always On Availability Group in a WSFC. Will it matter?

Comment: No was just clearing few things. Your diagram is confusing a bit. It seems you have 3 different WSFC and you want to add other instance such that instance secondary replica should be part of all there AG's correct ?

Comment: yeah im asking if each of the primary replica in each cluster can create a secondary replica in a new server. eveb though each are coming from different clusters. can the server (to the most left) be on each of the cluster?

Comment: Kindly see my answer

Answer (score 0):

Taking from your last comment

> yeah im asking if each of the primary replica in each cluster can create a secondary replica in a new server. even though each are coming from different clusters. can the server (to the most left) be on each of the cluster?

This is possible but you would have to use [Distributed Availability groups](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/availability-groups/windows/distributed-availability-groups?view=sql-server-2017) and should have Windows Server 2016 or above as OS.

Also note that the third server cannot be part of all WSFC(Cluster 1,2 ,3). If you want to achieve what you need you would have to create new WSFC and add new machine as part of it. Now you can configure distributed AG's to achieve what you need.

Comment: no. distributed AG solves different problem than this. Maybe above is not possible after all. thanks btw

Comment: What do you have in mind when you say "Dist AG's solve different problem". I believe Dist AG is the way if you want to implement. Apart from this I do not see any other way

Comment: Distributed AG works fine for DR part. DR Site in this case must use DAG. But you need SQL 2016..